# Match on specific words in a text file using regex using python

Tags: python-2.7

The text file is as below:
`$flower. are red, yellow and purple.`
`$Sun, and moon. are the best.`
`$Monkey, cat. are animals.`

I want to match the word after the dollar sign $ till the first dot and put then into list.

So the list should be:
`["flower","Sun, and moon","Monkey, cat"]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
import re
strings = re.findall('(?<=\$)[^.]+(?=.)', text)
```

The regex means "the dollar sign, followed by one or more symbols other than a period, followed by a single period and don't make the dollar sign and the period a part of the match". (?<=xyz) and (?=xyz) constructs are called lookbehind and lookahead respectively, they match the preceding and the following text but don't make it part of the match.

**EDIT** Sorry, didn't notice at first that you don't need the period and the sign.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to use the same technique with another words but it did not work, would you please correct it for me: I want to get the words between: 1. & 2. for the sentence  1. life is so good 
and every thing is ok. 2.

Comment: keeping in mind that there is a new line between every and thing ..... I have tried to make it ((?<=1.)[^.](?<=2.)) but it is not working